# google map javascript read json in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, for-loop

Hi I am new to javascript.  What is the best way to access a json object, "js" in this case, so that I can make each marker have a different content? Right now each marker displays the same key value(the last key value)

```
js = JSON.parse(jss);

var infowindow;
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: js.length + ' ' + iter//String(jss.length)
});
var iter = 0;

for (var key in js){

  mark = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(key*0.5,key*0.5),
  map: map,
  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(){
  infowindow.setContent(key.toString());
  infowindow.open(map,this);
  });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216351/google-maps-api-v3-for-loop-trouble
Solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a copy of key to pass into your onclick function each time the loop is executed, something like:

```
s = JSON.parse(jss);

var infowindow;
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: js.length + ' ' + iter//String(jss.length)
});
var iter = 0;

for (var key in js){

  var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(key*0.5,key*0.5),
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  var keystring=key.toString();
  google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(){
      infowindow.setContent(keystring);
      infowindow.open(map,this);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of for in, try to do with for loop,

```
for (var i=0; i<js.length; i++) {
    mark = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(js[i]*0.5,js[i]*0.5),
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'

}
```